# Mysql not responding for my query getting

Tags: mysql

My query is

```
select OldCreatorProduct.promekars_madeid, OldCreatorProduct.productIdType, OldCreatorProduct.mekarsId, oldCreatorMaster.mekarsId, OldCreatorProduct.productName, 
LEFT(OldCreatorProduct.promekarDescription, 150) AS 'Short Desc', OldCreatorProduct.promekarDescription, OldCreatorProduct.productMekarPrice, OldCreatorProduct.productAddDateM, oldCategoryMaster.productId 
from beta_icustommadeit.productmekarinfo AS OldCreatorProduct
INNER JOIN beta_icustommadeit.productmaster oldCategoryMaster ON OldCreatorProduct.productIdType=oldCategoryMaster.productId
INNER JOIN beta_icustommadeit.managemekars oldCreatorMaster ON OldCreatorProduct.mekarsId=oldCreatorMaster.mekarsId
INNER JOIN icmi_db.users nk on oldCreatorMaster.mekarsEmail = nk.email_id
```

Comment: Could do with a bit more info here

Answer (score 1):

Run `EXPLAIN` on the query to see the execution plan, and verify that the query is using suitable indexes.

Verify that the join predicates are on the correct columns. (Normative pattern for joins is from a foreign key column to primary key... there's not enough information for us to know if this is being done.)

Consider adding an additional predicates in a `WHERE` clause to cut down on the amount of work the query needs to do, if there are some rows that don't need to be returned.

No columns are being returned from `icmi_db.users`. (Is the purpose of the join to that table just to eliminate rows where `mekarsEmail` doesn't match?)

It's not possible to tell what you are trying to achieve with this query.

---

To diagnose performance issues, use **`EXPLAIN`** to see the execution plan.

[**8.8.1 Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html)

Make sure you have **suitable indexes** available.

And verify that the query is really going to return the result you need.

---

Some other notes:

We notice that the query is returning two columns of the same name `mekarsId`, likely you want to give one of those an alias.

And use backtick characters, not single quotes, to enclose/escape identifiers.

Personally, I'd reformat the query to make the query more decipherable, and to make the `EXPLAIN` output a little easier to work with (shorter table aliases).

```
 SELECT ocp.promekars_madeid
      , ocp.productIdType
      , ocp.mekarsId                     
      , ocr.mekarsId                      AS `ocr_mekarsId`
      , ocp.productName
      , LEFT(ocp.promekarDescription,150) AS `Short Desc`
      , ocp.promekarDescription
      , ocp.productMekarPrice
      , ocp.productAddDateM
      , ocm.productId
   FROM beta_icustommadeit.productmekarinfo ocp
   JOIN beta_icustommadeit.productmaster ocm 
     ON ocm.productId = ocp.productIdType
   JOIN beta_icustommadeit.managemekars ocr
     ON ocr.mekarsId = ocp.mekarsId
   JOIN icmi_db.users nk
     ON nk.email_id = ocr.mekarsEmail
```

Comment: Bless you for trying.